# Como puedo llenar varios JTexField con el contenido de un ArrayList?

Tags: java, java-swing, java-8, jtextfield

La duda en concreto es que cree JRadioButton de manera dinamica, es decir dependiendo de la cantidad que hay en un ArrayList. De la clase ManejadorArchivo se trae la informacion del usuario y se requiere mostrar en su respectivo JTextField. Este es un segmento de codigo:

```
    public void crearRadioButton(){
    ManejadorArchivo manejador = ManejadorArchivo.getInstance();
    ArrayList<Usuario> usuarios = manejador.getListaUsuarios();
    JPanel panelUsuarios = new JPanel();
    panelUsuarios.setLayout(new FlowLayout());


    Component botones;

    for(Usuario usr: usuarios){
        botones = panelUsuarios.add(new JRadioButton((usr.toString())));
        grupo.add((AbstractButton) botones);

    } 

    panel.add(panelUsuarios, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    panelUsuarios.setBounds(228, 11, 265, 378);

    panel.setVisible(true);
}
```

Lo que necesito es que a la hora de elegir el nombre de un usuario por medio los JRadioButton me muestre toda la informacion de cierto usuario seleccionado en los JTexfield asignados (Nombre, apellido Materno, Apellido Paterno).

Answer (score 1):

Si le agregas un ActionListener a cada JRadioButton al momento de crearlos, luego al codificar el metodo actionPerformed(ActionEvent event), podras invocar el metodo event.getSource() y castear a JRadioButton. Obtenido de esta forma el JRadioButton en cuestion, podras recorrer nuevamente la lista hasta encontrar el usuario cuyo toString() coincida con el nombre del JRadioButton obtenido y una vez obtenido el usuario completar con el los datos en los JTextFields.